# Vectorize quintuple for loop in numpy, with non-trivial indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a series of nested for loops, used to populate a rank-3 array as follows:

```
S = ...  # Some number
N = ...  # Some other number
an_array = np.zeros((S, N * N, N * N))
for s in range(S):
    for i in range(N):
        for a in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                for b in range(N):
                    an_array[s, i * N + a, j * N + b] = target[s, i, a, j, b]
```

This is equivalent to having indices in base `N` for the rightmost two dimensions of the array, where an element of the array is indexed as `an_array[s, ia, jb]`, except that the indices are converted in base 10 to work with numpy.

How can I populate the array in a vectorized fashion without resorting to for loops?

Thanks

Comment: `for s, i, a, j, b in itertools.product(range(5), range(4), range(4), range(4), range(4)):` can be used to avoid nested loops. But since this is an array assignment you can basically do this many columns or many rows at a time

Comment: Simply reshape : `an_array = target.reshape(-1,N**2,N**2)`?

Comment: Or for the second case, `target = x[:, :, :, None, None] - y[:, None, None, :, :]`, then do the same